Breakpoints related SASS variables doesn't seem to be taken into account when container related SASS variables are defined
I'm trying to override Vuetify $container-max-widths. This is what Vuetify does
$container-max-widths: () !default;
$container-max-widths: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'xs': null,
    'sm': null,
    'md': map.get($grid-breakpoints, 'md') * 0.9375,
    'lg': map.get($grid-breakpoints, 'lg') * 0.9375,
    'xl': map.get($grid-breakpoints, 'xl') * 0.9375,
    'xxl': map.get($grid-breakpoints, 'xxl') * 0.9375,
  ),
  $container-max-widths
);

I figured out that to override $container-max-widths first I have to override $grid-breakpoints, therefore I did this
// src/styles/main.scss

@use "vuetify" with (
  $grid-breakpoints: (
    "md": 960px,
    "lg": 960px,
    "xl": 960px,
    "xxl": 960px
  )
);

I basically want the same value from md and up. Then I used the v-container to check if the max-widths were properly updated, but it didn't seem to work. You can find a code sandbox here.

What am I doing wrong?

Please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be checked. It looks ok, this could work

@EstusFlask done

vuetify style import cannot override component styles because they were already imported with default global variables when a component was imported. This can be seen by disabling vuetify style import. Vuetify allows to override component styles through build-time transforms rather than providing module structure that could make these styles optional.
As shown in the documentation, this configuration is required:

configFile will be resolved relative to the project root, and loaded before each of vuetify’s stylesheets.

vite.config.js
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';
...
plugins: [
  ...
  vuetify({
    styles: { configFile: 'src/styles/settings.scss' }
  })

settings.scss
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
  $grid-breakpoints: (
    'md': 960px,
    'lg': 960px,
    'xl': 960px,
    'xxl': 960px,
  )
);


It works now, but I'm confused about one thing. Based on what it's written in the documentation, it's possible to keep both main.scss and settings.scss. Before bumping into this issue, I was using main.scss to add custom typographies. Shall I now move them to settings.scss or should I keep them in main.scss? If it's better to keep them in main.scss how does it change to account settings.scss usage?

The docs specifically mention this, "You can keep main.scss for other style overrides". I'd expect that anything that is not a variable override goes to main.scss

Yeah, it's true. But the doc also says that you can keep @use 'vuetify' but you have to remove with block. So it's not really clear to me how can I, for example, override the typographies without the with block. Maybe I'm missing something

It explains the reason, "configFile will be resolved relative to the project root, and loaded before each of vuetify’s stylesheets". You don't need "with" because it's already done for you by vite plugin

Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough, I'm sorry. I edited the codesandbox, could you look at it? I only have this last doubt, but after this I'll mark your answer as accepted

It's good as it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hp3wme . You override vars in "settings" and they  affect @use 'vuetify'

Ok, so once @use 'vuetify/settings' is used you place there all other overrides, even if they aren't component specific. Understood
